# How do multi-threading and infinite loops work together

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to learn python, doing exercise watching video online. I'm currently trying to do a multi-threading chat server but I think I have trouble understanding the way threads work.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->

import socket
import threading

class ThreadedServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port, buff_size):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.buff_size = buff_size
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            print('Waiting for a connexion...')
            self.c, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
            listening = listenToClient(self.c, self.addr)

class listenToClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client, address):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global socks
        socks.append(client)
        client.send(("Bienvenue sur le serveur, entre ton pseudo: ").encode('utf-8'))

        self.name = client.recv(buff_size).decode('utf-8')
        welcome = "Welcome " + self.name + "! If ever you want to quit, type {quit}"
        client.send(welcome.encode('utf-8'))
        msg = self.name + " has joined the chat"
        broadcast(msg)

        while True:
            msg = client.recv(buff_size).decode('utf-8')
            if msg != '{quit}':
                broadcast(msg, self.name + ": ")
                print('TEST6')
            else:
                client.close()
                leave_msg = self.name + " has left"
                broadcast(leave_msg)
                break                   


def broadcast(msg, prefix=''):
    for sck in socks:
        content = prefix + msg
        sck.send(content.encode('utf-8'))


def Main():
    ThreadedServer(host,port,buff_size).listen()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 10000
buff_size = 1024

socks = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The code is working ok for only one user.
I think the problem is in my comprehension of threads.
In my mind, when I type

```
listening = listenToClient(self.c, self.addr)
```

a new thread is created running in parallel with the first one. 
What I see in reality is that my new thread is indeed executing and ends in the infinite loop in here(managing whatever my first user connected is typing):

```
    while True:
        msg = client.recv(buff_size).decode('utf-8')
        if msg != '{quit}':
            broadcast(msg, self.name + ": ")
            print('TEST6')
```

But I thought as the original thread would have continued looping here:

```
    while True:
        print('Waiting for a connexion...')
        self.c, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        listening = listenToClient(self.c, self.addr)
```

Printing 'Waiting for a connection' and waiting for a second connection.
But it is not the case.

I'm pretty sure it's a misunderstanding on my side, I spent hours trying and trying changing everything etc, at some point the `listenToClient()` thread was just a method in the `ThreadedServer()`. But now I'm very lost and I don't know what to do, so I came here for help.

Thanks in advance,

Vincent

Comment: What's with all that work in your thread's `__init__`? `run` is the part that executes in a new thread.

Comment: Just a sidenote, multithreading in Python (in any language really, but Python especially) doesn't seem like the most effective way to learn the language.

Comment: @user2357112: That’s the answer right there.  (That and calling `start()`.)

Comment: `ThreadedServer` should not itself be a `Thread`.